# Font awesome does not resize

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am designing a website when suddenly my icons resized at a small scale.

I am using font awesome for my ICONS when suddenly the font awesome icon turns into small when the size is equal to the EVENTS name below

[image]

My code is

`<font size="6"><strong><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> EVENTS</font></strong>`

It must be like this

[image]

Can you help me guys? Thanks for future answers

Comment: This is the problem `<font size="6">` For one thing `<font>` is now obsolete.

Comment: Don't use font tag, place your text in a span and style the font there. Use the fontawesome on-site tutorials.

Comment: Wow, i haven't seen `<font>` used in some time!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not use `<font>`. That is a really archaic tag that shouldn't be used any longer. Instead, you'll want to use CSS. Something like:

```
i.fa {
     font-size: 1.5em;  // However big you want it to be
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other users said - don't use `<font>` tag, but set  the font-size with CSS.

However your code should work as you excpect. See snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<strong><font size="6"><strong><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> EVENTS</font></strong>
<hr>
<strong><font size="15"><strong><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> EVENTS</font></strong>
<hr>
<strong><font size="25"><strong><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> EVENTS</font></strong>
```

Comment: Rather than thanking in a comment, you can simply select the provided answer as a solution (whichever is appropriate) which will in turn convey your gratitude to the answer provider. Not just that, most importantly, it will help future users. Happy coding!